# SQL: WHERE & the AND-statement problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Wich i'll try to explain briefly

**TABLENAME:** EXAMPLE

```
Customer name | ProductClass
-----------------------------
 A            | Accessory
 B            | Accessory
 B            | Bicycle
 C            | Bicycle
```

**My goal:** 
Show Only the 2 rows of Customer B. So letting the query only show the custumors who have 2 value's for ProductClass

**If i attempt**

```
Select *
From Example
WHERE ProductClass LIKE 'Accessory'
AND ProductClass LIKE 'Bicycle'
```

I get no results

**If i attempt**

```
Select *
From Example
WHERE ProductClass LIKE 'Accessory'
OR ProductClass LIKE 'Bicycle'
```

I get all 4 the rows.

Comment: SQL is not English, you should not attempt to interpret it as such.  The reason why the `AND` example does not return any results is because `ProductClass` cannot be both `Accessory` and `Bicycle` at the same time.  It could be either or, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> show the custumors who have 2 value's for ProductClass

```
SELECT *
FROM Example e
INNER JOIN 
(
   select [customer name]
   from example
   group by [customer name]
   having count(*) = 2
) c on c.[customer name] = e.[customer name]
```

Comment: Ummm... exactly the same as my answer

Comment: I know... it's a Stack Overflow timing thing. When I first view the question, your answer is not here yet. I write and post my answer and move on. I come back after seeing the comment, and the timestamp clearly shows yours was first. I'll delete in a few minutes when you've had a chance to see this reply.

Comment: Or he'll accept my answer, which blocks me from deleting it :/

Comment: sigh... why do I bother :(

Answer (score 4):

```
Select [Customer name]
From Example
group by [Customer name]
having count(distinct ProductClass) > 1
```

If you want to get the entire row, then you could use

```
SELECT *
FROM Example 
WHERE [Customer name] in (
   Select [Customer name]
   From Example
   group by [Customer name]
   having count(distinct ProductClass) > 1
)
```

Comment: I think he wants to see both rows, with the productClass column

Comment: Just a minor issue with `NULL` values, but i guess that `Customer name` cannot be null, however, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Example e
INNER JOIN (
    Select CustomerName, COUNT(*) AS ProdClassCount
    From Example
    GROUP BY CustomerName
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- OR Maybe > 1
) x ON x.CustomerName = e.CustomerName
```

Comment: I think the inner query should also have the `WHERE` condition, WHERE `ProductClass = 'Accessory' OR ProductClass = 'Bicycle'`, otherwise, this could also return rows, for example, `WHERE ProductClass = 'SomethingElse'`

Comment: Not what they're asking for... they want all users who have 2 products regardless of which product.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [SQL INTERSECT](http://sql.sh/cours/intersect/) ?

```
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE ProductClass LIKE 'Accessory'
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE ProductClass LIKE 'Bicycle'
```

Comment: This will not work, since the column ProductClass  will be different in the queries